# Infinite dimensional operator inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, operator-theory

A is a linear operator on V and there exist a single operator B on V such that AB = I or BA = I. Prove that then A is monomorfic and epimorfic.

On infinite dimensions, left and right inverses need not be the same. But how to show that given at least one exists and is unique, the operator is regular?

Comment: If you have only a left-inverse **or** a right-inverse, the operator need not be invertible. It is invertible iff it has both, left- and right-inverse (and then the two are equal).

Comment: That is not true on infinite dimensions. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492006/example-of-a-linear-operator-on-some-vector-space-with-more-than-one-right-inver or http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42235/rings-with-right-inverses

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say. An operator can have more than one right-inverse, yes, but then it cannot also have a left-inverse. If it has both, a left-inverse and a right-inverse, then it is invertible, and the left-inverse is also the right-inverse. That holds regardless of dimension. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, then the existence of a left-inverse **or** a right-inverse already yields invertibility, but in the infinite-dimensional case, we _need_ to have the existence of both to deduce invertibility.

Comment: Ah, but I initially overlooked the last sentence, where the _uniqueness_ of the one-sided inverse is demanded. That changes the game, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linear operator is injective if and only if it has a left-inverse, and it is surjective if and only if it has a right-inverse.

To show that the uniqueness of the one-sided inverse implies the invertibility of $A$, show that if $A$ is not invertible, but has either a left- or a right-inverse, the one-sided inverse is not unique.

Say $A$ has a left-inverse, but is not invertible. Then $A$ is injective, and not surjective, so $A(V)$ is a proper subspace of $V$. Let $C$ be a complementary subspace of $A(V)$, i.e. $V = A(V)\oplus C$. A left-inverse of $A$ is then only determined on the subspace $A(V)$, but on $C$, it can be arbitrary. Then there are two different left-inverses given by $B_1(c) = 0$ and $B_2(c) = c$ for all $c\in C$. Since by assumption $C\neq\{0\}$, $B_1\neq B_2$, and $A$ has more than one left-inverse.

If we assume that $A$ has a right-inverse, but is not invertible, then $A$ is surjective but not injective, i.e. $\ker A \neq \{0\}$. If $B_1$ is a right-inverse of $A$, what modifications of $B_1$ lead to other right-inverses of $A$?

Comment: I am not sure. I think that the fact that A is not injective means that ker A contains MORE than a zero vector, and it has to contain the zero vector to form a subspace. So we can keep $B_1$ the way it is...?

Comment: Yes, $\ker A \neq \{0\}$ means $\ker A$ contains things beside $0$. Our aim is to show that the right-inverse of $A$ is not unique if $A$ is surjective but not injective. So suppose $B_1$ and $B_2$ are two right-inverses of $A$. What do you know about $B_2-B_1$?

Comment: It is nonzero and $A(B_2 - B_1)=0$, therefore in ker A... I mean, it sends each vector from V to ker A...

Comment: Yes. So, how do we show that $A$ has more than one right-inverse with that knowledge?

Comment: Each nonzero vector in ker A could be defined as an image of difference of two different operators...? Why can't we define them the same way as in the first case?

Comment: We can take any operator $N \colon V \to \ker A$, then $B_1 + N$ will also be a right-inverse of $A$. Conversely, we saw that the difference of any two right-inverses is an operator whose image is contained in $\ker A$.